# Sinatra/CouchDB error?

Tags: ruby, couchdb, sinatra

I'm working on my first Sinatra/CouchDB project and I'm getting an error I can't explain.

Here's my rackup (`config.ru`) file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'couchrest'
require 'patina'

set :environment, :development
set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
set :run, false

FileUtils.mkdir_p 'log' unless File.exists?('log')
log = File.new("log/sinatra.log", "a")
$stdout.reopen(log)
$stderr.reopen(log)

set :db, CouchRest.database!("http://127.0.0.1:5984/test")

run Sinatra::Application
```

And here's the app file (`patina.rb`):

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'couchrest'
require 'haml'

class Article < CouchRest::ExtendedDocument
  use_database settings.db

  property :title
  timestamps!
  view_by :title
end

get '/' do
  @db = settings.db
  haml :index
end
```

Without the class definition in `patina.rb`, the route returns a page that displays the `@db` property as I was expecting. However, when I add the class definition to `patina.rb` I get "Ruby (Rack) application could not be started" error message.

Obviously this has something to do with my class definition, but I can't figure out what the problem is and the error message doesn't seem that helpful to me.

Also, I'd actually prefer to have the class definition in a separate file (`Article.rb`), but I can't figure out how to do that in the context of my Sinatra app.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of googling, I discovered that the `1.4` series of `json.gem` are known to cause a lot of problems. I uninstalled all the json gems I had and installed `json-1.2.4.gem` instead. I have everything working correctly now. Here's the setup I'm using:

`config.ru` (Rackup file):

```
require 'application'

set :environment, :production
set :root, File.dirname(__FILE__)
set :run, false

FileUtils.mkmdir_p 'log' unless File.exists?('log')
log = File.new('log/sinatra.log', 'a+')
$stdout.reopen(log)
$stderr.reopen(log)

run Sinatra::Application
```

`environment.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'couchrest'
require 'haml'
require 'ostruct'

require 'sinatra' unless defined?(Sinatra)

configure do
  SiteConfig = OpenStruct.new(
    :title => 'Application Title',
    :author => 'Your Name',
    :url_base => 'Your URL',
    :url_base_db => 'Your CouchDB Server',
    :db_name => "Your DB Name"
  )

  # load models
  $LOAD_PATH.unshift("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/lib")
  Dir.glob("#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/lib/*.rb") { |lib| require File.basename(lib, '.*') }
end
```

`lib/contact.rb` (Model example, models auto-loaded in `environment.rb`):

```
class Contact < CouchRest::ExtendedDocument
  include CouchRest::Validation
  use_database CouchRest.database!((SiteConfig.url_base_db || '') + SiteConfig.db_name)

  property :name
  timestamps!

  view_by :name
end
```

`application.rb`:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sinatra'
require 'environment'

configure do
  set :views, "./views"
end

error do
  e = request.env['sinatra.error']
  Kernel.puts e.backtrace.join("\n")
  'Application error'
end

helpers do
end

get '/new/?' do
  haml :new
end

post '/save/?' do
  @contact_name = params[:contact_name]

  @contact = Contact.new
  @contact.name = @contact_name
  @contact.save

  haml :save
end

get '/' do
  haml :index
end
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the example of sinatra persisted with couch.

Answer (score 0):

try requiring 'patina' after setting :db.  I think the class body of Article is executing the use_database method before the setting exists.

you should be able to put Article in article.rb (ruby naming convention is UpperCamel for classes, but under_scores for the files in which classes are defined) and then require 'article' in patina.rb.

thats the only thing that stood out for me, so let me know if that works.

Comment: Hi, Ben - thanks for the reply. With those changes, I'm getting a different error: `undefined method `set' for #<Rack::Builder:0xb7b95a0c @ins=[]>`...

Comment: its defined in sinatra.rb, require 'sinatra' in the rackup

Comment: That just leaves me back at my original error: `stack level too deep` :(

Comment: The trace was about 3000 lines :/ I think I have it working now, though - see my edit above. Not sure why it works this way, but at least it's progress :)